# xargs overrides dialog's exit status

Tags: bash, dialog, xargs

I have a dialog created with the following code:

```
    exec 3>&1
    selection=$(echo " --backtitle \"Patches\" 
    --extra-button --extra-label \"See File List\"
    --title \"Patches\" --clear --ok-label \"Create\" --cancel-label \"Exit\" 
    --menu \"Please select:\" $HEIGHT $WIDTH 25 $gridData" |
    xargs dialog 2>&1 1>&3)
    exit_status=$?
    exec 3>&-
```

The dialog has an extra button in addition to Ok/Cancel pair (though I've renamed them). It works great unless the extra button is clicked, in which case $exit_status has the same value (123) as if the cancel button was clicked. Is there a way I can get dialog's status without xargs interfering with it?

Comment: You would only use `xargs` if you were trying to create multiple dialog boxes at once. There is no need for it here.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html#EXIT_STATUS) of `xargs`:

```
xargs exits with the following status:
  0 if it succeeds
  123 if any invocation of the command exited with status 1-125
  124 if the command exited with status 255
  125 if the command is killed by a signal
  126 if the command cannot be run
  127 if the command is not found
  1 if some other error occurred.
```

What are you trying to accomplish here? I don't see why you would need `xargs` in this case. You should instead call `dialog` directly, like so:

```
dialog --backtitle Patches \
    --extra-button --extra-label "See File List" \
    --title Patches --clear --ok-label Create --cancel-label Exit \
    --menu "Please select:" $HEIGHT $WIDTH 25 "$gridData"
```

This will work even if `$gridData` contains special characters (such as `"` or spaces).

Comment: dialog's exit status is important, because this is the only way to determine which button was clicked

Comment: @TichomirMitkov sorry, I want's clear. I meant, don't need `xargs` here, just call `dialog` directly.

Comment: I need it because of white space. $gridData contains fields, which are surrounded in double quotes.